# validating phone number with Parse.com Cloud Code

Tags: javascript, cloud, parse-platform, before-save

What I want is when a user enters in a phone number into an input field, my cloud code will validate it. Below is what I have so far.

```
Parse.Cloud.beforeSave("Contact", function (request, response) {
var Contact = Parse.Object.extend("Contact");
var query = new Parse.Query(Contact);
query.equalTo("PhoneNo", request.object.get("PhoneNo"));
query.first({
    success: function (object) {
        var filterPhone = /^((\+\d{1,3}(-| )?\(?\d\)?(-| )?\d{1,3})|(\(?\d{2,3}\)?))(-| )?(\d{3,4})(-| )?(\d{4})(( x| ext)\d{1,5}){0,1}$/;
        if (!filterPhone.test(object.value)) {
            response.error("Enter a valid phone number.");
            return false;
        } else {
            response.success();
        }
    },
    error: function (error) {
        response.error("Could not validate phone number.");
    }
});
});
```

I have used filterPhone below on the client side and that validates the phone number but I  cant seem to get it to work on the cloud.

```
var phone = document.getElementById('Pno');
            var filterPhone = /^((\+\d{1,3}(-| )?\(?\d\)?(-| )?\d{1,3})|(\(?\d{2,3}\)?))(-| )?(\d{3,4})(-| )?(\d{4})(( x| ext)\d{1,5}){0,1}$/;

            if (!filterPhone.test(phone.value)) {
                alert('Please provide a valid phone number');
                return false;
            }
```

Thanks in advance.

Thomas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't  understand the need for a query. I believe you want something like this:

```
Parse.Cloud.beforeSave("Contact", function (request, response) {
    var filterPhone = /^((\+\d{1,3}(-| )?\(?\d\)?(-| )?\d{1,3})|(\(?\d{2,3}\)?))(-| )?(\d{3,4})(-| )?(\d{4})(( x| ext)\d{1,5}){0,1}$/;
    if (!filterPhone.test(request.object.get("PhoneNo"))) {
        response.error("Enter a valid phone number.");
    } else {
        response.success();
    }
});
```

Am I missing something?

-Bob

Comment: Why the return? Is it neccessary?